# Video blacked out in screenshot of UIWebView

Tags: iphone, screen, screen-capture

I am having trouble capturing a screenshot of a `UIWebView` while it plays a video file.

I can capture when the video file is not playing and it is perfect but when the video file is playing in `UIWebView`, if I take a screenshot the video area is black and shows a QuickTime logo.

Can any body help me on this? I am totally frustrated. Any kind of help or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Hi, did you get the solution for this.. please guide me thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't think this is possible. It's a form of copyright protection either in the codec or the video library.

Answer (score 0):

So I did a little researching and maybe this is the way you are doing it however I would suggest maybe

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
[self.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
UIImage *viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

And maybe this is causing your video to go black, I am not a hundred percent sure however I would suggest maybe refreshing the web page if you take a screen shot inside of your application? It might look junker though depending on why the screen shot is being taken. Anyways hope this helps:)